# Unclear why (first order) satisfiability undecidable and not semi-decidable.

Tags: logic, computability

Hoping this will just be a terminology question, otherwise I have a bigger problem of harboring a misunderstanding re: decidability.

We know that (first order) satisfiability (for the general case of an arbitrary closed formula) is undecidable, and **not even semi-decidable**, by the following argument:

Validity is semi-decidable, by deciding it in terms of unsatisfiability, which is semi-decidable by the result that closed formulae in Skolem form are unsatisfiable if and only if they have a finite "segment" that is unsatisfiable.

If satisfiability were semi-decidable, then satisfiability and its complement, unsatisfiability would both be semi-decidable, so satisfiability would be decidable, in which case validity would be decidable, contradicting the negative answer to the Entscheidungsproblem of (general first order) validity.

Correct so far, even if not very rigorous?

My question then: We say satisfiability is **not** semi-decidable, even though its complement (unsatisfiability) **is** semi-decidable. So one must see 'semi-decidable' as a property of the specific decision problem, i.e. keep apart "x is satisfiable" and "x is not satisfiable", and not incorrectly think of satisfiability as semi-decidable because: "one half of the entire question is decidable, so the entire problem of satisfiability is semi-decidable."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but let me take a stab at it:

Your sentence

> One must see 'semi-decidable' as a property of the specific decision problem, i.e. keep apart "x is satisfiable" and "x is not satisfiable"

is **absolutely correct**. There are many senses in which two decision problems can be "equivalent," and the point is that semidecidability (or more commonly, *computable* or *recursive enumerability*) does *not* always respect these notions. For instance, every c.e. set is *Turing equivalent to* a co-c.e. set, but obviously no c.e. set is also co-c.e. unless it is computable. This is essentially the example you give of unsatisfiability for first-order formulas.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to describe what is confusing to me in the last paragraph: a formula being satisfiable is not semi-decidable, a formula not being satisfiable is semi-decidable. I suppose I want to say then "satisfiability (in general) is semi-decidable because "one half of it" is decidable", but that would be wrong. Correct?

Comment: No, that's not correct: satisfiability is not semi-decidable. **Un**satisfiability is semi-decidable. These two statements are *not the same*.

Comment: That's what I wanted to have confirmed. Sorry for the awkward phrasing. Will mark as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed but Turing equivalence is obviously far to crude to be relevant here, because it is based on oracles that give yes/no answers to membership tests. Many-one reduction gives the right notion of equivalence to be used in this context. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction.

Comment: @RobArthan of course you're right, that's part of my point; although satisfiability is "the same as" unsatisfiability with respect to Turing equivalence, it's not the same with respect to many-one equivalence, and this is the relevant notion of equivalence for c.e.-ness.