# Is satisfiability in First order logic always semi decidable?

Tags: logic

I know that finding whether a formula is unsatisfiable or a tautology is a semidecidable problem. But what about finding out if a formula is satisfiable ?

Comment: Or can we conclude that if a formula isnt unsatisfiable, then it is satisfiable. So satisfiability is also semi decidable ?

Comment: Satisfiability is not semidecidable - if it were, satisfiability would be both semidecidable and co-semidecidable, hence decidable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, you can put this an answer.

Comment: See the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327885/unclear-why-first-order-satisfiability-undecidable-and-not-semi-decidable.

Comment: @HansHüttel Thank you, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Satisfiability is not semidecidable - if it were, satisfiability would be both semidecidable and co-semidecidable, hence decidable.

---

A bit of commentary now:

There is something really deep going on here! Satisfiability is an **existential** property: $\varphi$ is satisfiable if *there exists* a model of $\varphi$. The beautiful power of the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) is that it tells us that **unsatisfiability** is *also* an existential property: $\varphi$ is unsatisfiable $\iff$ $\varphi$ proves $\perp$ $\iff$ *there exists* a proof of $\perp$ from $\varphi$. *(See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2099585/28111) for a bit more on this.)*

So both satisfiability and unsatisfiability "feel" semidecidable - a set is semidecidable, intuitively, if you can "search" for witnesses to it being true. But this isn't accurate: for a set to be semidecidable, those witnesses actually have to be things we can search *for* - i.e. natural numbers or things basically equivalent to natural numbers (like ordered pairs of natural numbers).

So the real question here is:

> How hard is it to "search" for a model? How hard is it to "search" for a proof?

A proof is a finite sequence of symbols from a finite alphabet, so searching for proofs is easy; so unsatisfiability is definitely semidecidable. By contrast, *models don't need to be finite*! E.g. the sentence $$(\forall x\forall y(f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y))\quad\wedge\quad(\exists x\forall y(f(y)\not=x))$$ is satisfiable but has no finite model (why?); even worse, there are satisfiable sentences with no *computable* models. So searching for models *isn't obviously* something we can do in an "effective" way, and indeed the undecidability of satisfiability shows that searching for models *is indeed not* something we can do.

(Interestingly, things switch around when we look at [*finite model theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_model_theory). When we restrict attention to finite models, models are definitely things that are easy to search for; however, *the completeness theorem breaks down*! So satisfiability becomes semidecidable, but there is no obvious reason for unsatisfiability to be semidecidable as well. And indeed [Trakhtenbrot's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trakhtenbrot%27s_theorem) shows that it is not. So things "switch around" when we shift from looking at *all models* to looking at *finite models only*.)